# Can metal implement a swap chain?

Tags: swift, graphics, metal

I tried to make it similar to the swapchain using

**renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction**,

but it wasn't possible because it fetched a drawable that wasn't the previous drawable.

Because drawable's texture cannot swapped, i think swap chain cannot implemented.

Can metal implement a swap chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Metal, swapchains are implemented by retrieving a new `MTLDrawable` from the `CAMetalLayer` on each frame, and retrieving the `MTLTexture` from that drawable.

The number of available drawables is very limited (typically 3), so you need to manage these carefully in your render loop.

Apple's documentation is not great on this topic, but you can find [more information here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/drawable_objects/creating_a_custom_metal_view). This document is written in terms of including the swapchain logic in a custom view, but you don't have to do so. You can write the swapchain as part of a separate renderer class, etc.